# Oracle CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, toad

Can someone help me with the below query in oracle?
The logic is that if the person has a friendlyname , use that for match with the 'search' criterion. Else, try to match with the realname column.

```
select * from people where   
case when customer_friendlyname is null then realname like '%abcd%'  
else   
case when customer_friendlyname is not null then customer_friendlyname like '%abcd%'  
end   
end
```

Appreciated if someone could take a look.. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, Boolean expressions can't be treated like other types of expressions; for example, `CASE` expressions can't evaluate to them. So you need to rewrite this.

In this case, since you have the same `LIKE '%abcd%'` predicate in both branches, you *could* just factor it out:

```
WHERE ( CASE WHEN customer_friendlyname IS NULL
             THEN realname
             ELSE customer_friendlyname
         END
      ) LIKE '%abcd%'
```

but it's simpler to make use of [the built-in `NVL` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm), and write:

```
WHERE NVL(customer_friendlyname, realname) LIKE '%abcd%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE (customer_friendlyname LIKE '%abc%')
   OR (customer_friendlyname is null and realname LIKE '%abc%')
```

You actually don't need the case here, this or clause will try the friendly name first it it was null it won't match, then it will try to match using the real name

Comment: If `realname` is `'abc'`, but `customer_friendlyname` is `'def'`, then I don't think the OP wants that record to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You also can write it this way:

```
select * from people where   
case
  when customer_friendlyname is null and realname like '%abcd%'
    then 1
  when customer_friendlyname is not null and customer_friendlyname like '%abcd%'
    then 1
    else 0
end = 1
```

But it is more convenient in the case when you have more expressions.